# Indesign: getting rid of footnote numbers in table of contents

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, table-of-contents

When I add my Table of Contents (Layout > Table of Contents), if some titles have custom footnotes, these will also show up in my TOC.

To get rid of them, I have to manually delete them and change the case of page number (from exponent to normal case).

Is there a way to automatically remove footnote numbers (or exponent) from the TOC?

The title

[image: The title]

The Table of Contents

[image: The Table of Content]

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and, by using mostly default settings for the `TOC dialog`, it will not include any footnote numbers in the generated `TOC`.

So i assume you are adding your *reference numbers* manually in the titles? If that's the case then yes manually inserted *reference numbers* are treated like normal text so they will get picked up in the `TOC`.

Proper footnotes (Type > Insert footnote) are ignored when generating a `TOC`.

[image: indesign table of contents]

Comment: You are exactly right. So, I may reformulate: how do I get rid of exponent numbers in ToC?

Comment: What are _exponent numbers_? Why not show us a screenshot of what you have? tnx

Comment: I updated the question..

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. As i mentioned in my answer above, if you insert _exponents_ (properly named reference numbers by the way) the right way (via Type > Insert footnote), these _will not_ show up in your TOC. Then you can control the page number formatting by making a special style for it (without superscript).

Comment: I was looking for a solution to remove superscript characters in ToC (maybe Grep?)

Comment: If you post your source file, or a part of it which includes the TOC and a few titles, i will fix this for you. CS6 or IDML format please